# IB vs Programmatical Creation of UIButtons

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibutton, memory-management

Let's say I want to create a lot of custom buttons with the same UIImage named X.
Programmatically, I would create only one UIImage and add this to all the buttons I created.
I was wondering if I created these buttons in Interface Builder would IB create only 1 UIImage X or a new UIImage X for each button?
Thanks

Comment: @tiw what do you mean by "create only 1 UIImage X or a new UIImage X for each button"? In IB you simply set the image for the specific state. Or do you mean, you'd like to create the buttons in IB and set the images in code?

Comment: @Nick my understanding of the question is whether using the same image in multiple places in IB will create one `UIImage` instance for each use or only one instance for each unique image resource. I believe it to be the latter, though it should be easy to verify.

Comment: @pmjordan might be, hope the OP answers.

Comment: so if i wanted to create 100 buttons totally programmatically i would be doing this once: UIImage *imageX = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageX.png"]; and setting it to my 100 different buttons. What if i created these buttons totally in IB and set their images also in IB? What would be the difference?

Comment: @tiw the difference is: you have more work to do in IB setting up 100 Buttons...on the other hand, with a good copy paste strategy this can be achieved quickly. When it comes to memory usage both approaches won't differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImages are pooled, so repeated calls to `[UIImage imageNamed:]` with the same name will actually return the same `UIImage` instance. This should apply to objects baked into a NIB as well. Should be easy to verify, though - just print out the pointer value using

```
NSLog(@"%p", [button imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
```

or whatever for each button in question.

Comment: Note that you might encounter reports of memory leaks etc. with regard to the UIImage's pool on the web - they were fixed way back in iOS 3.x, so aren't an issue nowadays.